# How to Train, Build , Deploy & Schedule a PredictionIO Model

Tags: apache-spark, predictionio

I am using PredictionIO Model to train, Build & Deploy as a service on a sample data set with default parameters.

Now I have a scenario where the dataset is getting huge day by day (incrementally) and I wanted to understand how PredictionIO Model detects the new data and trains it and deploys it according as a service?

As PredictionIO stores data in event server & capable of distributing the data using Apache SparkMLlib, How it detects there is new data available in the dataset?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi 
I hope **Apache Poi**  is nothing but Apache PredictionIO. If not i am really sorry. @AxelRichter

Comment: apologies @AxelRichter, Yeah You are right This question is not related to**Apache POI**. Thanks for help